# flutter type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter

I am getting error when trying to run in flutter
(type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

```
void _submitForm() {
//cek validasi form
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  FormFeedback formFeedback = FormFeedback(
      nameController.text, emailController.text, feedbackController.text);

  FormController formController = FormController((String response) {
    if (response == FormController.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
      _showSnackbar("feedback berhasil disimpan");
    } else {
      _showSnackbar("Error");
    }
  });
  _showSnackbar("Menyimpan Feedback");
  formController.submitForm(formFeedback);
}
```

I/flutter (18110): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Comment: Please post your code as text in a code clock. Pictures of code are impossible to search for and impact anyone with a disability that needs electronic help, since the usual tools work differently on pictures than on text. Last but not least, we cannot just copy your code into our IDE and test it when it's a picture.

Comment: check your json output, maybe something is null.

Comment: done, i was edited the post

Comment: and i was post my controller.dart code below

Answer (score 0):

Probably 'status' is int type and the callback expects String. Try changing the callback param to int:

```
void Function(int) callback;
```

or convert it to string:

```
callback(convert.jsonDecode(value.body)['status'].toString()));
```